# Query entre bancos diferentes em SQL Server

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Dada essa query:

```
    SELECT 
PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.N_FOLHA,
PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.NOME,
PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.EMPRESA_ID,
1 [ORIGEM]
FROM 
PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios

WHERE 1=1 
AND  NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT CodigoFuncPonto 
    FROM WebAdiantamento.DBO.funcionario
   WHERE FUNCIONARIO.CodigoEmpresa = 3
)

AND PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.n_folha = 11014
AND PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.empresa_id = 3
AND PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.demissao IS NULL
```

como podem ver ela faz consulta em bancos diferentes, não sei se isso e uma limitacao do sql server, porém ao incluir essa restrição nao tenho resultado

Por exemplo, o `funcionario` de codigo 11014 nao existe na tabela funcionario do banco de dados `WebAdiantamento`, logo deveria vir nessa consulta, porém na traz nada.

Desse jeito também não funcionou:

```
SELECT 
PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.N_FOLHA,
PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.NOME,
PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.EMPRESA_ID,
1 [ORIGEM]
FROM 
PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios

WHERE 1=1 
AND PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.N_FOLHA NOT IN (
  SELECT CodigoFuncPonto 
    FROM WebAdiantamento.DBO.funcionario
   WHERE FUNCIONARIO.CodigoEmpresa = 3
)

AND PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.n_folha = 11014
AND PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.empresa_id = 3
AND PontoSecullum4.DBO.funcionarios.demissao IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui Resolver, devido alguns registros no BD `WebAdiantamento` estarem nulos, 
nao conseguia fazer a comparação, então acrescentei um `isnull` na subquery e resolveu o problema.

```
isnull(WebAdiantamento.DBO.funcionario.CodigoFuncPonto,0)
```